Translating a Rego policy to AWS Cedar
I have the following dummy Rego policy
is_permitted if {
    owner := dataowner.resources[input.resource][input.resource_id].owner
    permitted_members := data.owners[owner].permissions[input.permission].members
    input.token.user in permitted_members
}

with the following data
{
    "owners": {
        "a-team": {
            "permissions": {
                "read": {
                    "members": [
                        "alice",
                        "bob"
                    ]
                },
                "write": {
                    "members": [
                        "alice"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "resources": {
        "database": {
            "db1": {
                "owner": "a-team"
            }
        }
    }
}

with the following input
{
    "permission": "write",
    "resource": "database",
    "resource_id": "db1",
    "token": {
        "user": "alice"
    }
}

It basically defines a team called a-team that have read and write permissions, specifying which members can read and which can write.
Then, we define a resource which is a database named db1 and we specify its owner are the a-team
The policy will return allow only if the user that sent the request (alice in our case) belongs to a team that has the matching permissions (read/write).
In our example, alice sent the request, wanting to write to db1.
Because alice belongs to a-team and has write permission in that team, and a-team are the owners of db1 - the policy will return allow.

I'm trying to do the same thing with AWS Cedar but have a bit of a hard time.
This is what I came up with so far, but no luck.
Cedar policy
permit (
    principal,
    action,
    resource
)
when { principal in resource.owner.permissions.action.members};

Cedar Entities
[
    {
        "uid": {
            "type": "PhotoApp::User",
            "id": "alice"
        },
        "attrs": {},
        "parents": []
    },
    {
        "uid": {
            "type": "PhotoApp::Owners",
            "id": "a-team"
        },
        "attrs": {
            "userId": "345623462345",
            "permissions": {
                "read": {
                    "members": [
                        "alice",
                        "bob"
                    ]
                },
                "write": {
                    "members": [
                        "alice"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "parents": []
    },
    {
        "uid": {
            "type": "PhotoApp::Resource",
            "id": "db1"
        },
        "attrs": {
            "owner": {
                "type": "PhotoApp::Owners",
                "id": "a-team"
            }
        },
        "parents": []
    }
]

Cedar Input:
Principal - PhotoApp::User alice
Action - PhotoApp::Action write
Resource - PhotoApp::Resource db1
Link to Cedar playground can be found here
Thanks!

Did you get it to work? Did you try in ALFA?
